# Typescript type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to loop through an object which holds a number of properties and the value is always an array of numbers. When I try to run the code below I get the error:

> property 'length' does not exist on type 'unknown'

When using Typescrip how do I assign a types when the object key/value pair is destructured in this way?

Thanks

```
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
      console.log(value.length)
   }
```

Comment: What’s the type of `object`/where does it come from? Ideally it would have a type that would encode that knowledge, so you don’t have to do anything on the loop side, but the best way to do that depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a type to the object beforehand.

```js
const object: Record<string, number[]> = {}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(value.length)
}
```

Read more about the [Record utility type here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

You can also type cast the object instead.

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object as Record<string, number[]>)) {
  console.log(value.length)
}
```

See all the examples in [TS playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/PTAEFEA8EMFsAcA2BTUBGAsAKAMYHsA7AZwBdQ8AjAK2RxICFoATALlACVa8AnJgHlLcAlgQDmAGlABXAgGsCeAO4EAfKAC8oAN4BfbNgBmPUAAp8xMgG1ZyAJ6SAbtERTkAXXIHQAeWq0SAHTIBCTCyEQmlDR0jEwAlHHa2KCg5kR4KAGIeKImTi7IWcGiJAAWcdh6WNggEDAIKKAATNhpZFH+bJz4vAKhIhKgBFKwFMjclm5qmrr6WEbcpm2g1naOzq4eeF6+0YHB-eGRfnQJSVgpaRmF2bn5rkViZRVYVTVgUHBIqADMrYSkcgnEhNLpcXqCAaSYajcaTabnFLQbjcaC2NBsSwABkkaEkTUkP0kABZJABWNziZKgZGo2yglYAcmgjMkjIorNAjJwnMZTF5yEZHhA4BRxjK3CUBFApXGyAAhKAAHJ4IYjMbcIg0xDZRTIJiVOa1T4NVDE-4WIF7H5gnr8SFiaHquFTDSImkotEYlY49D4wkk8mU6m0tEMyxkwOgInNXGSLFuQ3VLC1AAqtngqAAgoghNAiANsCQM6gALK2Xb+dOZt3dHj2-qOtWwiZTC2Ajp0YlscuVujV1AzEOe9GY3142PRqMUqkXD108OR0CkqeTicJpOGYxmAFWGz2UD3dyeHzAoIhMIRTtkfOgXvAgdnLTUq6ZW55DY3YrPTcp4CiyVFglKUZTleUt0WHdLVWA8jy2HYzwOS8TGfOdQ1sWJMUZAxoBsJVnW4XkDCkChkXlIVQEqGktXvPZH0SVDLgBa4shyD8CkeEpyl-IA)